# How to add fields like mobile number and nickname in magento customer registration form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, registration

I want to add fields Mobile Number, Nickname, Profession in the customer registration form. I've a followed a tutorial, through that I am able to get address and fax from the customers and fetch them back, But if I try for mobile number and nickname, the data is not being saved in Database, what do I do now? Plz help me here.

Comment: This might be useful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration

Answer (score 1):

add mobile to customer registration,customer edit page etc.
run following setup script from magento root.

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();



$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$vCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($vCustomerEntityType);
$vCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'mobile', array(
        'label' => 'Customer Mobile',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'forms' => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId, $vCustAttributeGroupId, 'mobile', 0);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override Account controller of customer module.you will follow this link to override controller in magento.http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/

Comment: Yeah, I've done this only. But the thing is Form is displayed with all fields, but data is not being entered into the database (the external fields which I've created nickname, mobileno etc. ).

Comment: check you have created columns to store this information and if created then use setAttributename() to store information in database

Comment: Not working, please anybody can provide step by step solution please.